# Radian and the length of a chord of a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

**Question**

In a circle of radius $r$, an arc of it is $2S$ long. Find the length of the chord corresponding to that arc (AB in the diagram below) .

**Details**

I got this question in a math test. And the answer of it is $2r \sin\left(\frac{S}{r}\right)$. But I could't find a way of solving it. Please need help. Regards !

**Diagram**

[image: diagram]

Comment: Do you know the definition of the sine function?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes I know what the sine function means and I understand basic trigonometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought it would be better for you to see an image of the result,

[image]

Comment: Your method is fine but it doesn't get the use of the arc of length $2S$. Please re-read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just join middle point of AB to O ;it is now easier to think out the answer than ask this question.